# c# JSONPatch not working with int and enums

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am try to implement ASP.NET MVC 5 WebAPI Patch. But there is a problem with int values and enums. JSON deserialize "think" that is better convert int to long, so is because that in my int propertie i recive allways 0...

So i found "Microsoft.AspNet.JsonPatch.JsonPatchDocument" (there has many others out ther)

Then problem is, i recive allways null in my model

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch( int id, [FromBody] Microsoft.AspNet.JsonPatch.JsonPatchDocument<Customer> model)
{
    //model is allways == null
}
```

I am using POSTMAN to send the patch as json in Body>Raw. Header is application/json.

I don´t understand why model is null... i need to do anything on WebApiConfig?

Still I tried to implements a custom JsonConverter, but the problem is i have a lots of Enum types, i need to create one for each enum? I try sothing like this:

```
 public class Int32EnumConverter<T> : JsonConverter
```

but the problem is in WebApiConfig.cs you need to implement this:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Int32EnumConverter<[I NEED HEAR Dynamic Enum Types>>);
```

There as any one to help me? Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use Json.net which is supported out of the box without you needing to register other serializers?

Comment: because JSON.net in http patch deserialize int in long...

Comment: I'm still failing to see what the problem is.

Comment: if you don´t know try your self create this

Comment: Can you share your `Int32EnumConverter<T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found! I did my on Delta Patch

```
 public class JSONPatch<T>
    {
        private Dictionary<string, object> propsJson = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        public JSONPatch()
        {
            Stream req = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;
            req.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
            string json = new StreamReader(req).ReadToEnd();
            propsJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
        }

        public JSONPatch(object model)
        {
            propsJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(model.ToString());
        }

        public void Patch(T model)
        {

            PropertyInfo[] properties = model.GetType().GetProperties();

            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!propsJson.Any(x => x.Key.Equals(property.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
                        continue;

                    KeyValuePair<string, object> item = propsJson.First(x => x.Key.Equals(property.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

                    Type targetProp = model.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).PropertyType;

                    Type targetNotNuable = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(targetProp);

                    if (targetNotNuable != null)
                    {
                        targetProp = targetNotNuable;
                    }


                    if (item.Value.GetType() != typeof(Int64))
                    {

                        object newA = Convert.ChangeType(item.Value, targetProp);

                        model.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(model, newA, null);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int value = Convert.ToInt32(item.Value);

                        if (targetProp.IsEnum)
                        {
                            object newA = Enum.Parse(targetProp, value.ToString());
                            model.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(model, newA, null);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            object newA = Convert.ChangeType(value, targetProp);
                            model.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(model, newA, null);
                        }

                    }

                }
                catch
                {

                }


            }
        }

    }
```

and now:

```
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch( int id, [FromBody]JSONPatch<Customer> model)
        {
....
```

Atention: not 100% tested! fail for null values.